# Form action outside the form

Tags: forms

Is there a way I can set the submit form action outside the form? For instance, this is what I have:

```
<input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
<input type='submit' value='Save' />
```

But I want to create a text link to effect the same action, something like:

> <...action here...>SAVE<...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="yourFormId" action="..." method="...">
    <!-- Your form fields -->
</form>
```

And later on your page:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('yourFormId').submit()">SAVE</button>
```